# Microsoft Access - Missing Reference to acrobat.tlb

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference

I am working with a Microsoft Access database that was mostly completed in Access 2010, and now I am opening it on a new computer that has Access 2013.

Upon opening the program, it tells me,

> "Microsoft Access database or project contains a missing or broken reference to the file 'acrobat.tlb' version 1.1."

I have done some research, and I know that I need to go into the VB code and go under `tools->references`.  Now under here it lists the working references then says,

> "MISSING: Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library"

So now I understand, that I need to give it the reference to that `.tlb` file.  I am good up to here, but whenever I try to browse I can never find this file.  I just downloaded Adobe, so I know I have the most recent version.

I saw a couple places in my research that you can just uncheck the box and try compiling again.  This however does not work for me.  it needs this reference for several things I am doing.

Has anyone ever had this problem or have any guidance for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Another thing I should add is that I also switch from windows 7 to windows 8.  So there is that transition in addition to the Access 2010 to Access 2013 transition

Comment: If you don't have the acrobat.tlb file in the adobe working directory most likely it is not the correct version to work with the sdk unfortunately. The acrobat versions come with it, however the reader (free) version does not. You can bypass this by retrieving the .tlb from the headers folder from the sdk, however you should still get an error cause the .tlb's class id won't match the acrobate's application class id. You could perhaps work around this provided that was the only way adobe sought to prevent use of sdk on free applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but loading Adobe by itself may not give you the library you are looking for. You could need the file which is located in the SDK (which happens to be free) [adobe site](http://partners.adobe.com/asn/developer/sdks.html). Try installing this, and see if you can navigate to the tlb.

Comment: I forgot my source: [found here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_20175433.html)

Comment: Thank you.  When you say the SDK, you mean the Adobe Air SDK, correct?

Comment: It looks like Adobe updated the site since the link was created. Try [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/downloads.html).

Answer (score 2):

SQL hound was right.  To expand on what he suggested and be more specific for this issue for those with this problem in the future, you need to download the Acrobat DC SDK (not the air one).  In InterappCommunicationSupport/Headers you will find acrobat.tlb.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Access 2013 and Acrobat Pro version 11.0.
I have looked for the file "acrobat.tlb" on my drives.
Found it under: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat"

In the Visual Basic Code "tools/references", I clicked "Browse" and went to the location I have found, selected the file and clicked OK. 
Returning back to "tools/references", the "Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library" is now available and selected.
I have run minimal code to open and show the number of pages of the opened "pdf" document and it returned the proper number of pages.

Just so you know:
I now remember that there was a selection called only "acrobat", it is now gone. Must have been caused by selecting manually the desired file.
Maybe that selection was pointing to the "acrobat.tlb" file. 
You can see the full path and name of the file corresponding to the selected library name at the bottom of the reference window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I had a Missing reference to "...Adobe 9...Type Library..." I unchecked that and tryed with, "**Acrobat Access 3.0 Type Library**" futher down. Then it worked.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: He can't comment - there's a minimum rep requirement.